# Laravel get all Datetime entries from Date ignore timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, date, eloquent

In my database a have a table with a column called date. In the date columns are datetime entries stored. Now I want to write a query that gets me all entries from a day.

Now If I do it like that I obviously get just the records with exact same timestamp

```
$date = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();

Task::where('date', $date)->get()->all();
```

But I need all records where the date is the same, no matter which timestamp they have

Comment: maybe you should specify your laravel version, it well help whether some helper function works on your laravel version. @Lx45

Comment: It's version 9.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a [whereDate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) function, which is what you're looking for:

```
Task::whereDate('date', $date->toDateString())->get();
```

However, Eloquent may cause some issues since you have the column named `date`, and it automatically scopes the where clauses for you. In that case, you'll need a raw command:

```
Task::whereRaw('DATE(`date`) = ?', [$date->toDateString()])->get();
```